# Could Nightblood eat away at metal minds?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, warbreaker

Using nicrosil or gold metalminds could you draw Nightblood?

Comment: You could presumably draw Nightblood regardless.  I assume you mean draw Nightblood without harming yourself?

Comment: Tapping any metalmind can fuel Nightblood.

Answer (score 2):

Nightblood can be fueled by tapping any sort of metalmind, see the Coppermind [here](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Feruchemy#Nightblood).